# QDBus Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus

Tags: 20.04, dbus, qdbus

I have working applications communicating over dbus, tried to setup docker some time ago and probably messed up something because my apps can no longer connect...

Right now when I try to run my app which uses qdbus I have

```
Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.
Please check your system settings and try again.
```

or when I even try to check currently running session bus'es with qdbus I'm getting

```
qdbus
Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/bus: No such file or directory
```

$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is set to

```
-bash: /run/user/1000/: Is a directory
```

$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

```
-bash: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus: No such file or directory
```

I tried to create bus directory under/run/user/1000 but then I'm getting connection refused

Would someone point what did I mess up

Comment: Ok, managed to make it work, I added export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= into .bashrc and it resolves path itself... 

But could someone explain it to me what was causing this?
I don't remember touching DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and if I don't change it in .bashrc its by default set to unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus